# Excel - sort one spreadsheet by exact order of second spreadsheet based on one column with same data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

I trying to find a way how to sort one spreadsheet into the same order like second spreadsheet - based on their one same column for example.

Here's an example what i need, i will make more sense like this. I was translating huge spreadsheet with thousands of phrases and each row has phrase in different language and ID, so a lot of columns. Spreadsheet i recieved was in order that wasn't based on anything, no alphabetical order or anything like that. I sorted it alphabetically for easier works, since there were a lot of duplicate phrases, but each phrase has unique id in same row but different column. I completed this translation and i want to return this spreadsheet to original order (i have old unsorted spreadsheet). Logical way how to do it is to sort finished spreadsheet based on column with IDs based on column in unsorted spreadsheet - so full spreadsheet returns to the original order - order based on ID.

Example:

Before sorting:

| **ID** | LANGUAGE 1 | LANGUAGE 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **2** | Hi | Hi2 |
| **4** | Bye | Bye2 |
| **1** | Hi | Hi2 |
| **3** | Bye | Bye2 |

After alphabetical sorting of column Language1 and changed column language2:

| **ID** | LANGUAGE 1 | LANGUAGE 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **3** | Bye | Cya |
| **4** | Bye | Cya |
| **2** | Hi | Ayo |
| **1** | Hi | Ayo |

What i want to achieve: i need to sort it "back" to original stat, or more exactly, sort whole spreadseet by matching sorting of ID column

| **ID** | LANGUAGE 1 | LANGUAGE 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **2** | Hi | Ayo |
| **4** | Bye | Cya |
| **1** | Hi | Ayo |
| **3** | Bye | Cya |

I am googling for last two hours and cant find any answers even thought i feel like this is simple logic which i believe should be possible.

Comment: Add a column with sequential numbering before doing the first sort, then sort on that column to restore the original order?

Comment: That's usually how I do it @cybernetic.nomad. I add SortKey columns for each sort method I would need.

Comment: If U are struggling with Sorting on ID then Alphabets then,, use Custom Sort,,, select first column ID in Ascending, then Sort by Language 1 A-Z or Z-A ,, hope this work for you,,, or better if possible share the WB with us & let us examine & fix the issue !!

Answer (score 1):

As you say "each row has phrase in different language and ID", I would suggest you use query formula to find the correct language 2 after translation.

On following image, I use Vlookup function to get the translated words in unsorted spreadsheet.

[image]